# Deploying a Django app on Apache + mod_wsgi with HTTP auth

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Is it possible to deploy a Django app on Apache + mod_wsgi ([the standard way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)) but with HTTP authentication in front of the whole thing?

Basically, I need an extra layer of HTTP security before any user, Django-authenticated or anonymous, is even able to reach the app.

Is this possible? If so, where do the Apache `auth` directives go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

With mod_wsgi on `/`, any resources to be provided by apache need to be listed as aliases.

Auth directives and host restrictions live in `Location` directives.

So I've disabled any apache access restrictions on things like css, and provided host/ip based access to another directory.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Servername              app.domain.example
        CustomLog               logs/access_log combined
        ErrorLog                logs/error_log
        DocumentRoot            "/home/app/apache/app/html"

        Alias /media/           /home/app/apache/app/html/media/

        <Location />
                Options None
                AuthType                Basic
                AuthName                "Login Prompt"
                AuthUserFile            /path/to/passwd.file
                Require                 valid-user
        </Location>

        <Location /media>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Satisfy any
        </Location>

        WSGIDaemonProcess       app user=app group=app processes=5 threads=1 display-name=app_WSGI
        WSGIProcessGroup        app
        WSGIScriptAlias         /       /home/app/apache/app.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I'm taking to liberty to edit out of your answer the unnecessary details, and leaving just the gist of things.

Comment: Perhaps there more detail then necessary. Glad I didn't add the `Expires` handling for static files now! Alway happy to leave working apache config's in places people can find them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But since I'm pretty newbie on that stuff. Would you mind explaining how to create that passwd file?

Comment: @GuilhermeDaviddaCosta: I don't actually use the apache password file, I just dropped it in here as an example of auth. There's documentation for managing [apache password files here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, here is example from one site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName djangoproject.domain.biz

  DocumentRoot "/home/user/websites/djangoproject/website/"

  WSGIDaemonProcess djangoproject python-path=/home/user/.virtualenvs/djangoproject/lib/python2
.6/site-packages/ user=user group=user threads=1
  WSGIProcessGroup  djangoproject
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/websites/djangoproject/website/django.wsgi

  <Directory "/home/user/websites/djangoproject/website/">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "By Invitation Only"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
    Require valid-user
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Note that setting DocumentRoot to be where your source code is, including settings.py with database passwords, is a bad idea. If you were to comment out WSGIScriptAlias all your source code can be downloaded. It is also good practice to stick django.wsgi in a subdirectory and only set up the Allow from all for that specific sub directory. You have setup access privileges for whole source which is why DocumentRoot is so dangerous in your case.

Comment: Excellent point, I will leave answer unedited for further reference.